# Nodemon unable to find file from typescript build

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nodemon

I am attempting to use nodemon to run a node server in one of my projects with a react frontend. When I attempt to use yarn to invoke nodemon, I receive the following errors:

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/Users/william/Documents/GitHub/cribbageNginx/my-app/server/build/helperFunctions' imported from /Users/william/Documents/GitHub/cribbageNginx/my-app/server/build/index.js
    at finalizeResolution (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:272:11)
    at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:649:10)
    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:692:13)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:97:40)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:243:28)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:42:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:41:36)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

To reproduce this error, I run the following commands.
From the github repository, https://github.com/wjonesusna2012/cribbageNginxServer

in the /my-app/server directory, I run yarn build (which builds successfully) and then yarn start which returns the above error.
I can see that the helperFunctions file exists in the server/build folder so I'm confused as to why that file cannot be found in the import statement.

For brevity's sake, the package.json and tsconfig files are included here, with all files available in the above link.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

server/package.json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.tsx",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.9",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.20",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon",
    "build": "rm -rf ./build && tsc --project ./"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "commonjs": "^0.0.1"
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you importing that file somewhere dynamically in run time?

Comment: I can't imagine that I am unless nodemon is doing something I don't understand. The import statement in question is: import HelperFunctions, { deck } from './helperFunctions';

Comment: what if you add the extension of the file in your import ? import HelperFunctions, { deck } from './helperFunctions.js'

Comment: in your tsconfig.json try to add:
"files": ["./server/build/helperFunctions.js"],

Comment: It does happen at the top of the file. The problem I see with your suggestion is that the file is actually a typescript file that in the yarn build command is compiled with tsc with the resulting javascript files going to the ./build directory. tsc, not I, generates the javascript files that I'm trying to run. If manually add the extension after yarn build, it does indeed solve that problem, but I get a second error: ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at file:///Users/william/Documents/GitHub/cribbageNginx/my-app/server/build/index.js:3:20

Comment: I still would like to avoid the process of going in and changing the extension to a file that comes as the result of a build process.

Comment: you are right just trying to figure out any possible solution:)
I encountered similar errors when i was importing files in run time so basically there werent compiled to the build. but i guess you have a different issue

Comment: Hey I appreciate the help regardless, misha1109. Thanks!